# Bypass Varnish cache if user is logged in

Tags: cache, cookies, varnish

Is it possible to bypass the Varnish cache when the user is logged in? I've tried using the "CraftSessionId" cookie, but it seems that it is also set for non logged in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CraftSessionId` is just the [PHP session cookie](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) renamed, so you'll get it on every request that requires session, regardless if they are authenticated with Craft or not.

The Craft authentication cookie is a cookie with a 32 character randomly generated name.  i.e. `7afe5904f6b2a09ce620eca02e80328c`.

Comment: Thank you Brad! There is also another cookie ending with "username" i.e. `7afe5904f6b2a09ce620eca02e80328cusername`, I guess it's safe to use it too?

Comment: Yeah, that's just for populating the username on the login page.  You can either allow it or set https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#rememberUsernameDuration to `false` to disable that feature.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is to test the cookie for a name with username in it, and pass if it exists. You could also check for an exactly 32 digit alphanumeric cookie name I guess.

```
if (
 req.http.Cookie ~ "username" # Craft sessions have the word username in them
)
{
    return (pass);
}`
```